# Combining thrust and boost's odeint; incorrect pointer passing believed to cause segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, thrust, odeint

I am trying to modify the lorenz_parameters.cu example from [boost::odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/index.html) to solve the initial value problem for many initial-conditions. The program segfaults, and I believe that this is caused by my incorrectly passing pointer(s) to the call of `integrate_adaptive()`, as when I try to print out the size of the vector for storing the derivative, it is 0.

For reference, here is the [documentation for the example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/using_cuda__or_openmp__tbb_______via_thrust.html), and the [code for the same examples](https://github.com/boostorg/odeint/tree/master/examples/thrust) (for some reason the links to the code in the original documentation do not work).

I have attached below the full source code for the program. There is a line marked `UNEXPECTED OUTPUT!`, where I try to print the size of the derivative vector, and it comes up as 0, where it should be the same size as the state vector (512). There is also a line marked `LINE I DO NOT UNDERSTAND`, which is where I think I may be doing something wrong. This line is part of the call to intergrate_adaptive(), and I think that this argument is what is passed (eventually / by way of the odeint package) to the `operator()` function in `parallel_initial_condition_problem`. But I am trying to do the same as is in the example, and yet it is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef double value_type;

//change this to device_vector< ... > of you want to run on GPU
typedef thrust::host_vector< value_type > state_type;

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const size_t D = 16; // how many values of each initial condition to try
const size_t N_ICS = D * D; // number of initial conditions
const size_t N_VARS = 2; // number of variables in the system

// time constants
const value_type t_0 = 0.0;
const value_type t_final = 0.1;    
const value_type dt = 0.01;

struct parallel_initial_condition_problem {
  struct functor
  {
    template< class T >
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()( T t ) const
    {
      const value_type k_b = 0.45/6.0;
      const value_type k_f = 1.0;
      const value_type k_d = 1.0;

      // unpack the variables (and the parameters we want to vary, if any)
      value_type f = thrust::get< 0 >( t );
      value_type a = thrust::get< 1 >( t );
      // value_type df = thrust::get< 2 >( t ); // this also causes a segfault
      // value_type da = thrust::get< 3 >( t );
      // calculate the derivative
      thrust::get< 2 >( t ) = -0.01; // minimal value for debugging
      thrust::get< 3 >( t ) = -0.01; 
    }
  };

  parallel_initial_condition_problem( size_t N )
  : m_N( N ) { }

  template< class State , class Deriv >
  void operator()(const State &x , Deriv &dxdt , value_type t ) const
  {
    //// Printing out debugging info (here is the error..but why?)
    cout << "INSIDE operator()" << endl;
    cout << "t: " << t << endl;    
    cout << "size of x: \t" << boost::end(x) - boost::begin(x) << endl;
    cout << "size of dxdt: \t" << boost::end(dxdt) - boost::begin(dxdt) << endl; // UNEXPECTED OUTPUT!!
    cout << endl;

    thrust::for_each(
      thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
        thrust::make_tuple(
               boost::begin( x ) + 0*m_N,
               boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N ,
               boost::begin( dxdt ) + 0*m_N,
               boost::begin( dxdt ) + 1*m_N
               )
                 ) ,
      thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
        thrust::make_tuple(
               boost::begin( x ) + 1*m_N,
               boost::begin( x ) + 2*m_N ,
               boost::begin( dxdt ) + 3*m_N,
               boost::begin( dxdt ) + 4*m_N
               )
                 ) ,
      functor() );
  }

  size_t m_N;
};

int main(int /* argc */ , char** /* argv */ ) {

  // x stores both (initial) state (x) [0:N_VARS*N_ICS] and dxdt [N_VARS*N_ICS:END]
  state_type x( 2 * N_VARS * N_ICS ); 

  // DUMMY INITIAL CONDITIONS FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
  // fill each value with its index
  for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++) {
    x[i] = 0.01+i;
  }

  // system function
  parallel_initial_condition_problem init_con_solver( N_ICS );

  //////////////////////////////// Debugging info: (all seems correct here)
  cout << "POINTERS"  << endl;
  cout << "size of x: " << boost::end(x) - boost::begin(x) << endl;
  cout << "x    :" << &(*x.begin()) << endl;
  cout << "dxdt :" << &(*x.begin()) + N_VARS*N_ICS << endl;
  cout << "end  :" << &(*x.end()) << endl;
  cout << endl;

  /////////////////////////// STATE_T      VALUE_T      DERIV_T      TIME_T
  typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type , value_type , state_type , value_type > stepper_type;
  const value_type abs_err = 1.0e-6;
  const value_type rel_err = 1.0e-6;
  integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( abs_err , rel_err , stepper_type() ),
              init_con_solver ,
              std::make_pair( x.begin() , x.begin() + N_VARS*N_ICS  ), /// LINE I DO NOT UNDERSTAND
              t_0, t_final, dt );

}
```

The output of running this is:

```
$ g++ main.c && ./a.out
POINTERS
size of x: 1024
x    :0x9a2010
dxdt :0x9a3010
end  :0x9a4010

INSIDE operator()
t: 0
size of x:  512
size of dxdt:   0

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some includes missing. Try with

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/thrust/thrust.hpp>
```

Actually I wonder, why your code even compiles. If you use the current odeint version from boost (1.55) you also need to specify the algebra and the operations type:

```
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<
    state_type ,
    value_type ,
    state_type ,
    value_type ,
    thrust_algebra ,
    thrust_operations > stepper_type;
```

This should change in the next boost release. For the gihub version of odeint your code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment led me to check which version of odeint I had installed, and it was 1.54 (the current default in ubuntu's libboost-all-dev package). I downloaded the latest version and included it, as well as the #include that you mentioned above, and it worked. I have also added `thrust_algebra` or `thrust_operations`, but it didn't seem to need them to work. Thank you!

Comment: If you use boost 1.55 you must add the `thrust_algebra` and the `thrust_operations`. It might compile and even run, but then it will not use the GPU. We have added automatic algebra and operations dispatching in the github version of odeint and in the next release of boost (v 1.56).